# UVa#11340 python TLE

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem: [11340 - Newspaper](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/113/11340.pdf)

I use **dict** to store the values and characters as the key. I read every line of the input as a string and see if each character in every line has value in **dict**.

Here's a message it tell us:

> Each line can be up to 10000 characters length. Be aware of alargeinput size, the whole inputfile is about 7MB.

But I think I could just ignore the message above. Here's my code:

```
def main():
    test_case = int(input())

    for t in range(test_case):
        number_of_paid_characters = int(input())
        paid_character_dict = {}
        for n in range(number_of_paid_characters):
            paid_character, value = input().split()
            paid_character_dict[paid_character] = int(value)

        paid = 0
        number_of_lines = int(input())
        for n in range(number_of_lines):
            line = input()
            for character in line:
                paid += paid_character_dict.get(character, 0)

        print("{:.2f}$".format(paid/100))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My output is identical to the accepted output in uDebug. [uDebug #11340](https://www.udebug.com/UVa/11340)

I think there're probably something wrong with string processing, but I have no idea of it.

I tried sending my code several times but keep getting **Time Limit Exceeded**. Are there any way to improve my code?

Comment: Please indent your code, it doesn't run.

Comment: @alDiablo thanks. Now it can run.

Comment: That's the entire point of the exercise, see if _you_ know of a better algorithm to solve the problem faster or more efficiently. Do the work.